# Detecting a returned empty set in MySQL to then print a message

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a procedure in MySql to take a given first name and last name and print out associated information from tables about the people. I have all those pieces working. The problem is when some enters a valid first and last name rather then just returning an empty set I would like to return a message to the user.

```
delimiter //
create procedure pHW2_5_mmirkovi(IN fname varchar(25), IN lname varchar(25))
BEGIN
   IF fname IS NULL OR fname = '' THEN
       SELECT ('Please enter a valid first name,it cannot be null or empty') as Message ;
   ELSEIF lname IS NULL OR lname = '' THEN
       SELECT('Please enter a valid last name, it cannot be null or empty') as Message ;
   ELSE 
        SELECT first_name, last_name, c.cid, 'name', year, semester, grade
       from dreamhome.Students s, dreamhome.Courses c, dreamhome.Students_Courses sc
       WHERE s.sid = sc.sid AND c.cid = sc.cid AND first_name = fname AND last_name = lname;
   END IF;
END ;
```

I am getting
[image]

I want to get:

[image]

Comment: Please read first https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and make a [mre] for startes replace the comma seperated tables with JOIN and try first your query without procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can use next trick:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pHW2_5_mmirkovi(IN fname varchar(25), IN lname varchar(25))
BEGIN
   IF fname IS NULL OR fname = '' THEN
       SELECT 'Please enter a valid first name, it cannot be null or empty' as Message;
   ELSEIF lname IS NULL OR lname = '' THEN
       SELECT 'Please enter a valid last name, it cannot be null or empty' as Message;
   ELSEIF EXISTS(
       SELECT 1 
       FROM Students s
       JOIN Students_Courses sc ON s.sid = sc.sid
       JOIN Courses c ON c.cid = sc.cid
       WHERE
          first_name = fname AND last_name = lname
   ) THEN
       
       SELECT 
            first_name, last_name, c.cid, 'name', year, semester, grade
       FROM Students s
       JOIN Students_Courses sc ON s.sid = sc.sid
       JOIN Courses c ON c.cid = sc.cid
       WHERE first_name = fname AND last_name = lname;
   ELSE
       SELECT CONCAT('Student ', fname, ' ',  lname, ' not found') as Message ;
   END IF;
END ;
```